# What are the hashes for the various flavours of Ubuntu?

Tags: hash

The hashes posted on [Ubuntu Hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) do not mention 14.04.1. Where and what are the hashes for the 14.04.1 images?

Answer (score 2):

The hashes for Ubuntu 14.04.1 can be found at http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/MD5SUMS.

They are reproduced here for convenience:

```
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
c4d4d037d7d0a05e8f526d18aa25fb5e *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
01545fa976c8367b4f0d59169ac4866c *ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
08d25bf879e353686a974b7b14ae7d81 *ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso
119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
a4fc15313ef2a516bfbf83ce44281535 *ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
ca2531b8cd79ea5b778ede3a524779b9 *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso
3aa14ca13d52df070870d39306f4a4eb *ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso
b31731ea6cdbebe1d02f8193db420886 *wubi.exe
```

---

The hashes for Kubuntu 14.04.1 can be found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS

They are reproduced here for convenience:

```
aefdc97d26e51066f5b50d36c5d4218c *kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
327cf4202f8e2601ce0d772082c84b86 *kubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
d1eabbb0060ad45c1172877c726f0a5a *kubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
854cb04fcc0277abe1259f39a32d8f46 *kubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

---

The hashes for Xubuntu 14.04.1 can be found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS

They are reproduced here for convenience:

```
ae446659057ee49e57773bf446398856 *xubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
ccd326466b705bc324a20dd45cb3de82 *xubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
8b06ac9d76186721312c17a851801e2e *xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
ac7829d1b274f4d8b6ac106ec5985c9f *xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

---

The hashes for Lubuntu 14.04.1 can be found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS

They are reproduced here for convenience:

```
d3181e58212e62b6656c8cf5f9b922a7 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-amd64+mac.iso
dc6d7ee644b825cae63f59c91d707852 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-amd64.iso
35a41aa73bfe3c47a57d49a5182e9891 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-i386.iso
4d9e511daf41dbc44f4506958f0e70f9 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-powerpc.iso
2cfdcc5162f70515f4b59c80a142e36b *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
c138cedb0f72cbd115c55e3f14a98f5e *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
b0d1c58c8515ab40382d01f59655ba85 *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
2ca3784e4575214c13c85effca9dd4ae *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-powerpc.iso
2bf5abe48007c247ec214ec4e7681558 *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64+mac.iso
a5f97cd6a9f171c70cf816de8728f13b *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso
a7c153f1101fb8a181ccda01a448ffd1 *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-i386.iso
69d8c99a4724ddb281c9076fd9c8d771 *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-powerpc.iso
ebb98a27efd717fee62077e2d492c704 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
4a6555869fbbe11fa6a17f83be046455 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
281fc36d625f7ca0704297b3b811fa66 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
0af2df006d5220832f5a713bd9ba9d82 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-powerpc.iso
```

---

The hashes for Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1 can be found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS

They are reproduced here for convenience:

```
167e35018d4e4e116342e744f09d07f4 *ubuntu-gnome-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
ab5c39caef103694fe97bda23412ff00 *ubuntu-gnome-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
31ac57691a45a381ded0ab2a3588b77a *ubuntu-gnome-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
a3965d4e20d8c85dbaa5c36c6898fe5d *ubuntu-gnome-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

---

The hashes for Edubuntu 14.04.1 can be found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS

They are reproduced here for convenience:

```
ca19c5f5cc790603a6a9a57fae787673 *edubuntu-14.04-dvd-amd64.iso
1919086a97af4092342933a5eccbab62 *edubuntu-14.04-dvd-i386.iso
f4f047e216eb3ca28650a213476c4e56 *edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso
66f7711a226e4c764c2c3b977693543a *edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-i386.iso
```

---

For all the official flavours, you can replace the MD5SUMS in the link with SHA1SUMS to get the file with the SHA1 hashes:

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/SHA1SUMS
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/SHA1SUMS
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/SHA1SUMS
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/SHA1SUMS
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/SHA1SUMS
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04/release/SHA1SUMS

## NOTE

The cdimage and releases websites don't have HTTPS. You should verify the PGP signatures of the hash files. You can obtain them by appending a `.gpg` to the links, such as http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/SHA1SUMS.gpg

Comment: The truly security paranoid should also verify the various GPG hashes for the MD5SUMS files to ensure you're being served the right file (and not a MITM-generated version). If HTTPS versions were available, that would be better.

Comment: @Oli I have added a note to that effect.